# Is possible test one observable attribute in the service from component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmine-marbles

I don't know if this that I want to do is possible, I have one component `FiltersComponent` and one Service `FiltersService`.
In FiltersService I have one attribute onFilterChange of type BehaviorSubject. I expose it asObservable and I want to test when I applied the change this observable is throw.

```
FilterService.service.ts

export class FilterService {
    private _onFilterChange$: BehaviorSubject<any>;
    constructor() {}

    get onFilterChange(): any {
        return this._onFilterChange$.asObservable;
    }

    public onApplyFilter(filter) {
        this._onFilterChange$.next(filter);
    }
}
```

```
FilterComponent

export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    filterForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private _filterService: FilterService){}

    onApplyFilter() {
        const pfilter = this.filterForm.getRawValue();

        this._filterService.onApplyFilter(newF);
    }
}
```

How can I test when I apply a filter

```
this._filterService.onApplyFilter(newF);

this._filterService.onFilterChange().subscribe(d => {
    respond the same filter that I apllied 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question's tags, I could see that you are using `jasmine-marbles` to test the observables. If so then you should set up your `FilterService` like this:

```
export class FilterService {

    private _onFilterChange$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    constructor() {}

    get onFilterChange(): Observable<any> {
        return this._onFilterChange$.asObservable();
    }

    public onApplyFilter(filter) {
        this._onFilterChange$.next(filter);
    }
}
```

To Unit test, `FilterService`, have the following code in `filter.service.spec.ts` file:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {cold} from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { FilterService } from './filter.service';

describe('FilterService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({}));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: FilterService = TestBed.get(FilterService);
    const expected = cold('a', {a: 2});
    service.onApplyFilter(2);
    const p = service.onFilterChange;
    expect(p).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```